# Swift encode input URL to be as the final URL the browser shows

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, url

On my iPhone, when I paste "zerø.info" into a browser (chrome/firefox) and search, then I see the URL turn to "zer%c3%b8.info" and then it's turned into "xn--zer-2na.info".
In my project (iPhone app), when I call `urlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)` I get "zer%c3%b8.info".
How can I get the final URL "xn--zer-2na.info" in Swift 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "[IDNA encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)", which is basically the [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) of the domain name prefixed with "xn--". There is no built-in way of generating this in Swift, according to [this forum post](https://forums.swift.org/t/idn-punycode-in-url/35358/15).

There is a CocoaPod called [PunycodeSwift](https://github.com/gumob/PunycodeSwift) that generates these. For example,

```
"zerø.info".idnaEncoded // xn--zer-2na.info
```

Note that this returns an optional, since this conversion can fail if e.g. the result is longer than the allowed 63 characters of a host name.

Also note that not all browsers support this.